# Issue in getting the textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code I have a textbox which is kept visible *false* and its default value is *0*. When I click the button for the first time, it takes 0 value and for next time it takes empty. 0 value is not taken for next time. Please help me to do this.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="productPanel" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        Details are loading... Please wait
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="productPanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnusableLoss" Text="0" runat="server" visible="false" style="width:70%" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, false);" >
        </asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string val=   txtUnusableLoss.Text.ToString();
}
```

Comment: _"0 value is not taken for next time"_ means that it takes the empty string? By the way, why do you use an `UpdatePanel` for a single `TextBox`, where is the button and what does the js-function `isNumberKey`?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter  Yes 0 value is not taken for next time.There are many controls so i place update panel . find the issue in this textbox so i placed only one

Comment: share your full aspx code?

Comment: you use aspx code dropdownlist or radiobuttonlist?

Comment: What does your code behind look like? Does anything interact with the textBox? Maybe you have some code that sets the textUnusableLoss text to "" hence the subsequent errors after the first reload of the update panel